# Navigation error - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

After developing an application using codeigniter,i have uploaded files to my server.I can successfully open the homepage but cannot navigate further.When i navigate `404 error` is shown.Application has all the pages inside folders.

Also have given the baseurl as current folder :

```
http://www.xxxx.com/abc/
```

Routes :

```
$route['login'] = "home/login";
```

As a beginner in Codeigniter have no clues on whats happening.
Note : Updated Htaccess file:

```
IndexIgnore *
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/php/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /assets/php/403.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#These are the original rewrites, but might cause problems with some server configs.
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|user_guide|robots\.txt)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#These conditions are tested to work, and should be a better alternative to the commented ones above.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Any help..

Comment: and how your `.htaccess` looks like ? check in root directory and paste code, if that doesn't exist, create a new one

Comment: @Viral no htaccess added

Comment: you may need index.php `http://www.xxxx.com/index.php/abc/`

Comment: `routes.php` as follows:

`$route["login(.*)"] = "home/login$1";`

Comment: Then, try `http://www.xxxx.com/index.php/abc/` if you succeed, add a new htaccess. Get help from [here](https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750)

Comment: @wolfgang1983 it loads the domain xxx.com

Comment: @utility if you have not set up your htaccess and codeigniter config.php to remove your index.php then in every url needs to have index.php `redirect('index.php/somepage)` and or `<?php echo base_url('index.php/somelink');?>`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 let me create htaccess then..

Comment: I use this link quite a bit https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter good for windows users have not tried any on linux yet

Comment: What is your default controller in your config file?

Comment: Also try adding `RewriteBase /abc/` on your .htaccess